# simple_form_for doesn't recognise f.input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using the simple_form gem. I have a fairly straightforward scenario. I have a scoped route and I'm trying to get a form:

```
= simple_form_for(@scope, @post) do |f|
  = f.input :comment
```

Simplified routes file:

```
scope ':scope' do
  resources :posts
end
```

However I get the error:

```
undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x7f1b1eef1cb8>
```

I'm using rails 3.0.12 and simple_form 1.4.2

Any advise where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around it this (although not ideal is to use simple_fields for. I'll stick with this until there is a better solution.

```
= form_for(@scope, @post) do |f|
  =f.simple_fields_for :posts do |ff|
    =ff.input :comment
```

Answer (score 3):

This is occurring because the `simple_form_for` (and the `for_form` too because `simple_form_for` is only a method delegation to it) receives as second argument the options hash. So your `@post` is being interpreted as options, preventing to the SimpleForm to change the form builder.

The correct way to work with scoped resource is using a array like this:

```
= simple_form_for([@scope, @post]) do |f|
  = f.input :comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you restart the server after installing Gem?

Comment: yes. If I hadn't then the error would be around the simple_form_for, not the input